# Angular 2 local storage - "has no exported member" compilation errors

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-local-storage

Thanks in advance for any help. I am trying to get local storage access in Angular 2 with typescript. I am using the npm package angular2-localstorage. I had the angular.io "Tour of Heroes" working (without much styling). I followed the instructions at https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-localstorage. After adding the suggested code to my app.module.ts file, I tried running with `npm start`, and get the following compilation errors:

```
node_modules/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.ts(46,9): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/joshuaforman/Documents/CodeCraft/a2quickstart/a2-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/lang"' has no exported member 'Type'.
node_modules/angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter.ts(47,9): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/joshuaforman/Documents/CodeCraft/a2quickstart/a2-angular/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di"' has no exported member 'provide'.
```

You can see all the code here: https://github.com/joshuaforman/angular2-quickstart

In addition, here is the full app.module.ts file (the only one I've changed that causes the errors to occur):

```
import { NgModule }       from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule }  from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormsModule }    from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule }    from "@angular/http";

// added for LocalStorage
// followed instructions here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-localstorage
import { LocalStorageService, LocalStorageSubscriber } from "angular2-localstorage/LocalStorageEmitter";

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from "angular2-in-memory-web-api";
import { InMemoryDataService }  from "./in-memory-data.service";

import { AppComponent }        from "./app.component";
import { HeroDetailComponent } from "./hero-detail.component";
import { HeroesComponent }     from "./heroes.component";
import { HeroService }         from "./hero.service";
import  { DashboardComponent } from "./dashboard.component";

import { routing } from "./app.routing";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),
    FormsModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroesComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent,
        DashboardComponent
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers:    [
        HeroService,
        LocalStorageService // added for Local Storage
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
  // added for Local Storage
  constructor(storageService: LocalStorageService) {}
}
```

I have a comment with every line that I added to implement local storage that contains the text "LocalStorage". If you comment out those three lines, compilation and runtime works fine.

At this point, I just want to be able to compile successfully. Thanks.

Note: this is my first question on stack. I've found many answers here in the past, and I've tried my best to follow conventions in asking this question. Any productive feedback on what I should do differently in asking is welcome.

Comment: Last I knew angular2-localstorage wasn't compatible with the last few releases of Angular.  The github even lists that it isn't maintained anymore.  I would recommend switching libraries if you need Local/Session storage.  I found [Angular2 Cool Storage](https://github.com/Hacklone/angular2-cool-storage) works nicely

Comment: Well, that would do it, wouldn't it? I'll give Cool Storage a try over the weekend and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I confirm that this library isn't compliant with the latest angular2 releases. You should use one of the others that manage the webstorage. Like Dave V said, you can use angular2 cool storage or [ng2-webstorage](https://github.com/PillowPillow/ng2-webstorage) that i created some months ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular2-LocalStorage is no longer maintained, you'll have to use another library till this one gets an active maintainer.  I recommend Angular2 Cool Storage

Comment: Thank you. This does solve the compilation error. However now I get a runtime error. When following the readme and I add this line to my app.module.ts file `imports: [CoolStorageModule]`, I get this error: `zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:3000/angular2-cool-storage 404 (Not Found)`. Any help you can provide on this?

Comment: One thing I notice is that in my network tab, zone.js:1274 initiates a lot of gets, all for .js files. Except for angular2-cool-storage, which has no .js extension, and is the only file that has errors. I have uploaded my code trying to use cool storage to my git repository - https://github.com/joshuaforman/angular2-quickstart

Comment: I figured it out. In addition to the instructions in the readme, I had to setup the system.config.js file to use Cool Storage. I guess this is what an experienced Angular 2 dev would know what to do. Specifically I added this line to the map property: `"angular2-cool-storage":  "npm:angular2-cool-storage"` and add these lines to the packages property: `"angular2-cool-storage": {
        main: "./cool-storage.js",
        defaultExtension: "js"
      }`

Comment: I should have thought of that, it's just been a while since I used SystemJS, totally forgot that part.  Glad it's working for you though!

Comment: I appreciate the help you gave me. Cool Storage is great, and very easy to use. I up-voted your answer, but I don't have enough stack rep for it to show.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this lines from "LocalStorageEmitter.ts" from node_modeule "angular2-localstorage"

```
import {Type} from "@angular/core/src/facade/lang";
import {provide} from "@angular/core/src/di";
import {ComponentRef} from "@angular/core";

export function LocalStorageSubscriber(appPromise: Promise<ComponentRef<any>>) {
    appPromise.then((bla) => {
        bla.injector.get(<Type>LocalStorageService);
    });
}
```

with this.

```
import {Type} from "@angular/core/src/type";
import {Provider} from "@angular/core/src/di";
import {ComponentRef} from "@angular/core";

export function LocalStorageSubscriber(appPromise: Promise<ComponentRef<any>>) {
    appPromise.then((bla) => {
        bla.injector.get(<Type<any>>LocalStorageService);
    });
}
```

It's Works for me...

For more Details => https://github.com/marcj/angular2-localstorage/issues/66